# Помогите разобраться со знаками

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлены тире? Петр в прошлом – учитель в школе, завуч, а сейчас – безработный, нуждающийся в постоянной помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно поставили тире. 
Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому. См.:[Грамота.ру](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=615.Yywvxk4_i6ld_V8dLYFnMpgjFr8_iRpPa0ATGKfxFig.913536fb0723acb228f70135b5abc476db43ddca&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjTibK6ICh6iYNbEoR8c-LynPH2mh_zXKXjId5KWWVUpYzIQNoJC_Tl08uiZ6_Zcg6mvUeyY7WtZCExQSQVVQOCwkkMgeWDFnNe_XdO1eEnPzmaXwkds2tWGcvy1lk1YiXn9CEc1zBqjWDUlq6ryPFaw9zUqD6MIWXPdXRb354vdgVvd7r_Ma4LUw&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDeWxFblpCb3hxNnZiNUxCVHFOem5CbTAzQmFqTGZNTEVmak4wRGdtbVo5T0djZkVLRDc1Y2FBbHVmQS1aTnBkWVkwaFRLTXluVUZZY1FWZ2hMNDYtZw&b64e=2&sign=0481d35c35c6f4437c4e2a4eff49d211&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O7szC0fU2plaEj4fuaRrJKnAcODucO5e7-OYQ3zeCDSi9fou7oVRvAH&l10n=ru&cts=1425297491548&mc=2.2516291673878226)

Comment: Спасибо! )

Comment: Серж,не поняла Вашего объяснения.При чём здесь противопоставление и неожиданное присоединение? Здесь тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными им.падежом сущ.